# conditional pdf with independent identically distributed standard normal random variables.

Tags: probability-distributions

Random variables X and Y are independent identically distributed standard normal random variables. Consider random variables U=aX+bY and V=aX-bY, where a and b some fixed numbers and a^2 +b^2 =1.

a. Determine the joint pdf fuv, using the Jacobian formula.

b. Determine the conditional pdf fu|y(u|y=1).

I solved the part a by applying Jacobian's formula. I think the random variable should be normal distributed. However, after I simplify it, it looks very complicated.

I got determinant det(Ju,v(x,y))=2ab. 
fu,v=(fx,y(U+V/2a, U-V/2b))/|det(Ju,v)|. since X,Y are iid, 
(fx(U+V/2a)*fy(U-V/2b))/2ab=(1/4abPi)exp(-(u^2-2(a^2-b^2)uv+v^2)/8a^2b^2))

I donot know where I made mistakes. I also confused about part b. Could anyone help me out? Thank you very much.

Comment: Random variable X and Y are independent identically distributed standard normal random variable. Consider random variables U=αX+βY and V=αX-βY, where α,β are some fixed numbers and α^2+β^2=1.
 Determine the joint pdf f_(U,V) using Jacobian formula.
 Determine the conditional pdf f_(U|Y) (u│y=1).
My answer to part a:
                        U=(X+Y)/2α, V=(U-V)/2β.  Det(J_(U,V))=2αβ.
                        f(U,V)=(1/2αβ)(1/2π) e^(-((u+v)/2α)^2-((u-v)/2β)^2 )
                                 = 1/4αβπ e(-(u^2-2(α^2-β^2 )uv+v^2 )/8α^2 β^2)

Answer (score 0):

There is not one but two random variables $U$ and $V$ and they are *jointly bivariate normal*. Although you've written it out pretty unreadably and I don't feel like parsing it, it looks like you're on the right track at the very least. This joint PDF might look a little unfamiliar to you. You can find it [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Density_function) under the heading "Bivariate case" but you might have to do some algebra to get it into this form (You can compute the means, variances and correlation of $U$ and $V$ from standard formulae).

For the conditional $PDF,$ since $X$ and $Y$ are independent you can basically set $Y=1$ and write $U\mid_{Y=1} = aX +b$ so it has the same distribution as $aX+b.$ (If they weren't indpendent you'd need to use the conditional distribution of $X$ given $Y$.) Alternatively you could compute the joint distribution of $U$ and $Y$ by similar methods as above and then use the formula $$ f(u\mid y) = \frac{f(u,y)}{f(y)}.$$

Comment: I think I confused about the symbol. The professor did not explicitly explain it as you did. But I still feel my joint density function was wrong although I was on the right track. If you have some time, would you show the solution? Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: I came up with different solutions for part b. Since X, Y are independent, I worked on the distribution aX+b. However, which function do I need to start with? pdf of fx or pdf of fu,v? Would you explain it further for me? Thank you.